# Inline javascript validation does not work for jsp files

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am working on a java based web application which is being designed using jsp and servlets. I am having a difficulty with a form validation script in my project.

I need to include an external javascript file in one of my jsp pages.

I tried to include it in this way in the jsp page.

The validation script looks like this:

https://github.com/nirmaniPathiranage/Hotel-Property-Management/blob/master/WebContent/js/script.js

And the form looks like this:

https://github.com/nirmaniPathiranage/Hotel-Property-Management/blob/master/WebContent/Register.jsp

But when I am running the application, the system behavior seems like no script is running. The expected validations are not activated.

I have no idea about this. I have included both the .js and .jsp files inside the WebContent folder of the project.

I can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no spaces in your path `type="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Property Management System/WebContent/js/script.js"`. Remove the spaces in `Property Management System` and try. It should work.

Comment: Thank you so much Nitin. It worked! I've been staring at that code for a long time trying to find the errors. Thanks again.